# Include sender address in disclaimer (incoming mail)

Tags: exchange-server

I have a mail flow rule setup to flag email from outside our domain.  It prepends a disclaimer into the email.  Today I saw an email from another domain that included the **senders email** address and **friendly name** in their disclaimer (see below).

[image]

Below is the disclaimer text i use in my rule.  What code would i need to insert **(ADDRESS HERE)** for Exchange to insert the senders email and friend name?

```html
<p><div style=’border:solid #9C6500 1.0pt;padding:2.0pt 2.0pt 2.0pt
> 2.0pt’><p class=MsoNormal style=’line-height:12.0pt;background:#FFEB9C’><b><span
> style=’font-size:10.0pt;color:#9C6500′></span></b><span
> style=’font-size:10.0pt;color:black’><span style="background-color:
> #FFFF00"> [EXTERNAL SENDER (ADDRESS HERE) - Use Caution Opening Links or Files]</span><br><br><o:p></o:p></span></p>}
```

Comment: I found the answer in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/signatures?view=exchserver-2019#format-your-disclaimer)

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld That is for outgoing mail from your domain. Does not help with the transport rule i'm asking about on incoming mail from outside domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days with MS tech support, it turns out that this is not possible with Exchange Server.

Turns out this can be done in Cisco ESA.